# Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am getting following errors :

```
Notice: Undefined index: oid in C:\wamp\www\var\de\products.php on line 9

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\var\de\products.php on line 45
```

Can any one guide me how to fix this :

```
<?php

include('all.php');
include('product.php');

$product = new Products();


$order_details = $product->loadOrderDetails(intval($_GET['oid']));

print $order_details;

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Debug Test</title>

</head>
<body>


    <br/>

    <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" width="90%">
        <tr>
            <th>Order id</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th colspan="2">Order Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$order_details['order_id'];?></td>
            <td><?=$order_details['ordered_on'];?></td>
            <td colspan="2"><?=$order_details['order_total'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
        </tr>
<?php
    foreach ($order_details['products'] as $pid => $info) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$info['name'];?></td>
            <td><?=$info['description'];?></td>
            <td><?=$info['price'];?></td>
            <td><?=$info['qty'];?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Customer Information</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <?=$order_details['customer_info']['username'];?><br/>
                <?=$order_details['customer_info']['company_name'];?><br/>
                <?=$order_details['address']['street'];?><br/>
                <?=$order_details['address']['city'].', '.$order_details['address']['state'].' '.$order_details['address']['zip'];?><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

all.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Fake database access
 * @return array customer info
 */
function getCustomerInfo() {

    return array (
        1=>array(
            'customer_id' => 1,
            'username'=>'george',
            'address_id' => 3,
            'created_on'=>'2005-01-28',
            'company_name'=>'Foo Inc.',
        ),
        2=>array(
            'customer_id' => 2,
            'username'=>'sam',
            'address_id' => 2,
            'created_on'=>'2005-10-09',
            'company_name'=>'Foo Inc.',
        ),
        3=>array(
            'customer_id' => 3,
            'username'=>'harrison',
            'address_id' => 1,
            'created_on'=>'2005-07-21',
            'company_name'=>'Bar Inc.',
        )
    );
}

function getAddresses() {
    return array(
        1 => array(
            'address_id' => 1,
            'street' => '123 Main St.',
            'city' => 'Some City',
            'state' => 'PA',
            'zip' => '12345'),
        2 => array(
            'address_id' => 2,
            'street' => '345 Garden Dr.',
            'city' => 'Manhatten',
            'state' => 'NY',
            'zip' => '55555'),
        3 => array(
            'address_id' => 3,
            'street' => '876 Over There BLVD',
            'city' => 'Atlanta',
            'state' => 'GA',
            'zip' => '88899'));
}

/**
 * Fake database access
 * @return array customer info
 */
function getOrderInfo() {
    return array (
        1=>array(
            'order_id' => 1,
            'ordered_on'=>'2006-11-17',
            'ordered_by'=>1,
            'order_total' => '47.00',
            'products'=>array(
            array('product_id' => 5, 'qty' => 2),
            array('product_id' => 6, 'qty' => 1),
            array('product_id' => 7, 'qty' => 3))
        ),

        2=>array(
            'order_id' => 2,
            'ordered_on'=>'2006-10-17',
            'ordered_by'=>1,
            'order_total' => '4.00',
            'products'=>array(
            array('product_id' => 1, 'qty' => 3),
            array('product_id' => 2, 'qty' => 1),
            array('product_id' => 7, 'qty' => 2))
        ),

        3=>array(
            'order_id' => 3,
            'ordered_on'=>'2006-11-12',
            'ordered_by'=>3,
            'order_total' => '43.00',
            'products'=>array(
            array('product_id' => 5, 'qty' => 1),
            array('product_id' => 6, 'qty' => 2))
        )
    );
}


/**
 * Fake database access
 * @return array customer info
 */
function getProducts() {
    return array (
        1=>array(
            'product_id' => 1,
            'name'=>'Product A',
            'description'=>'Fancy Product with options',
            'price' => '10.00',
        ),
        2=>array(
            'product_id' => 2,
            'name'=>'Product B',
            'description'=>'Fancy Product with options',
            'price' => '10.00',
        ),
        3=>array(
            'product_id' => 3,
            'name'=>'Product C',
            'description'=>'Fancy Product with options',
            'price' => '20.00',
        ),
        4=>array(
            'product_id' => 4,
            'name'=>'Product D',
            'description'=>'Fancy Product with options',
            'price' => '5.00',
        ),
        5=>array(
            'product_id' => 5,
            'name'=>'Product E',
            'description'=>'Fancy Product with options',
            'price' => '13.00',
        ),
        6=>array(
            'product_id' => 6,
            'name'=>'Product F',
            'description'=>'Fancy Product with options',
            'price' => '15.00',
        ),
        7=>array(
            'product_id' => 7,
            'name'=>'Product G',
            'description'=>'Fancy Product with options',
            'price' => '2.00',
        )
    );
}

function print_array($a) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($a);
    echo '</pre>';
}


?>
```

Product.php

```
<?php

class Products {

    var $name;
    var $description;
    var $productId;

    function Products($id = 0, $infoArr = array()) {
        if ($id > 0 && count($infoArr)) {
            $this->name = $infoArr['name'];
            $this->description = $infoArr[''];
            $this->productId = $id;
        }
    }



    /**
     * @static
     */
    function loadAllProducts() {
        $arr = getProducts();
        $prods = array();
        foreach ($arr as $id=>$info) {
            $prods[$id] = new Products($id,$info);
        }

        return $prods;
    }

/**
 * function loadOrderDetails
 * 
 * This function should be giving us all the information about the order:
 * The customer's name and address, the products that were ordered (deescriptions too) and the order totals.
 * See products that php to see what is expected to be shown
 *
 * @param Integer   $order_id   the unique identifier for the order
 * @return Array    $cur_order  the details of the order
 * 
 */
    function loadOrderDetails($order_id) {
        $orders    = getOrderInfo();
        $products  = getProducts();
        $customer  = getCustomerInfo();
        $address   = getAddresses();


        return $order_id;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Where are inputs with names?

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from this line and its because you are trying to access a variable that isn't set.

```
$order_details = $product->loadOrderDetails(intval($_GET['oid']));
```

You pass GET parameters through the URL like `products.php?oid=123` and you will get this error if you **don't add** this to the URL.  So I suggest you change your code to check to see if the variable is set before using it.  Something like

```
if(!empty($_GET['oid'])) {
    $order_details = $product->loadOrderDetails(intval($_GET['oid']));
}
```

Your second error is related to the first.  Because `$_GET['oid']` doesn't exist it means that `$order_details` is presumably empty.  So you also need to do a check further down in your code before you do your `foreach` to check that $order_details isn't empty

Answer (score 1):

The array in question is `$_GET[]`... which means...

Are you calling your file with that variable? Something like http://example.com/something.php?oid=123?

Because that's what it's looking for - it looks like all the other errors are cascading consequences of this error.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying the read field that wasn't set. Perphaps it happens when you call your script without `oid` parameter, e.g. `products.php?oid=12345`. So instead of believing that you have value set in `$_GET['oid']` please check if it is set, e.g. with `isset($_GET['oid'])` and basing on this you can make decision whether or not try to load products etc.